# How can I have the Google Vision detect web entities API return more than 15 web entities?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I've used the detect web entities API on https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web, but it always seems to return 15 web entities, even when I set maxResults to something larger, such as 50 or 1000. Is there any way to have the web entities API return more web entities?

Here is my request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 50
        }
      ],
      "image": ...
```

Comment: for all images?

Comment: Yes, I would like to set the maximum number of web entities the API returns when called on any image.

Comment: The limited 15 per image, is happening with all the images you send?

Comment: Yes, it happens with all the images I input to the API.